# Run two different curl in script on 1st/2nd and 3rd/4th Monday of the month

Tags: bash

I am looking for ideas how to run two curl commands in a bash script, first for every 1st and 2nd Monday of the month, and second every 3rd and 4th of the month:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#run every 1th and 2nd Monday of the month
curl https://url1.com

#run every 3rd and 4th Monday of the month
curl https://url2.com
```

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/a/429617/340330

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just run your curls using crontab?

A thing like :

```
00 00 * * 1 [ $(date +\%d) -le 14 ] && curl https://url1.com
```

Comment: To clarify, that will run at midnight (`00 00`) on every day (`*`) of every month (`*`) that's a Monday (`1`). The command uses `date` to check to see if it's being run on or before the 14th of the month, and only if so run the curl. Similar logic can be used for the other curl checking for the date `-ge 15`.